# Callbacks: Difference between DAQmxRegisterDoneEvent() and DAQmxEveryNSamplesEvent

Tags: callback, nidaqmx

Trying to figure out how callback wrappers are called specifically. Our code deals with a `slowTask` and an `onTask`. During a `slowTask`, I deal with the following two lines (specific to this question):

```
DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming(slowTask, "OnboardClock", GUI_RATE,
      DAQmx_Val_Rising, DAQmx_Val_ContSamps, 1);
DAQmxRegisterEveryNSamplesEvent(slowTask, DAQmx_Val_Acquired_Into_Buffer, 1,
      0, EveryNCallbackWrapper, this);
```

I understand that here, everytime the buffer fills up with one sample, `EveryNCallbackWrapper` will be called.

For an `onTask`, I have a hardtime understanding how the callback gets called. I consulted the NI documentation but couldn't quite get it.

```
DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming(onTask, "OnboardClock", ON_RATE, DAQmx_Val_Rising,
     DAQmx_Val_FiniteSamps, 100);
DAQmxRegisterDoneEvent(onTask, 0, DoneCallbackWrapper, this);
```

This one boggles my mind a bit more. I believe that whenever onTask is triggered (with a hardware trigger), the DAQ starts taking and digitizing analog measurements at ON_RATE samples/second and once 100 samples are taken/read into the DAQs buffer, the `DoneCallbackWrapper()` is called. Depending on how long this hardware trigger stays high, this wrapper will be called every time the DAQ reads 100 samples (while trigger is high) OR will the callback be called only once after 100 samples were read?

Comment: What are the DAQ devices in use?

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen PXIe-6363 (the system itself consists of a lot more modules but this is the only DAQ card in our PXIe Chassis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The callback is called only once after 100 samples were read

Because `slowTask` uses `DAQmx_Val_ContSamps`, the program asks for an **infinite** (aka continuous) acquisition where data is streamed to the host. Using the `EveryNSamples` callback allows the program to access and process the newest data that was sent by the device.

Because `onTask` uses `DAQmx_Val_FiniteSamps`, the program asks for a **single** acquisition of `100` samples. Using the `Done` event allows the program to access and process the complete and full acquisition.

In your comment update, the program uses

```
DAQmxCfgDigEdgeStartTrig(onTask, "/PXI2Slot4/PXI_Trig0", DAQmx_Val_Rising));
```

to configure a [digital edge start trigger](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370471AM-01/TOC17.htm) for `onTask`. When that trigger line has a rising edge, the `onTask` acquisition begins, captures 100 samples, stops, and invokes the callback.

If the program needs to acquire 100 samples for `onTask` for *every* rising edge on `/PXI2Slot4/PXI_Trig0`, you can use the [retriggerable property](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370471AM-01/mxcprop/attr190f/) on the NI 63xx series devices that allows the same task to [re-run for each trigger event](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/5382/en/).

More details are in the [X Series User Manual](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/370784k.pdf):

> The AI Start Trigger is also configurable as retriggerable. The timing engine generates the sample and convert clocks for the configured acquisition in response to each pulse on an AI Start Trigger signal.
>
> The timing engine ignores the AI Start Trigger signal while the clock generation is in progress. After the clock generation is finished, the counter waits for another Start Trigger to begin another clock generation. Figure 4-22 shows a retriggerable analog input with three AI channels and four samples per trigger
>
> [image: illustration of retriggerable analog input signals]

Comment: Hi, that was very helpful, thank you! I didn't realize that line was important for my question at the time, but the `onTask` actually does have a DAQmx trigger call:
```DAQmxCfgDigEdgeStartTrig(onTask, "/PXI2Slot4/PXI_Trig0", DAQmx_Val_Rising));``` so this just takes care of the jitter between the last `slowTask` sample and first `onTask` sample, but still means that `onTask` only acquires 100 samples. It would repeat that if I set the retriggerable property you mentioned, am I understanding this right?

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!